# How to add BoxDecoration when using Positioned

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a border to some text in the following widget:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            top: 70,
            right: 50,
            left: 50,
            child: Text(
              surprises[surpriseNumber]['Surprises'],
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.pink[700]),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

But I cannot work out how to do it. Based on answers I have found online I feel like this should work:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            top: 70,
            right: 50,
            left: 50,
            child: Text(
              surprises[surpriseNumber]['Surprises'],
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.pink[700]),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

But it fails with `The named parameter 'child' isn't defined.`

Is anyone able to point me to where I am going wrong here?

Comment: `Text` widget cannot have any `child` widget - you need to revert the order: first `Container` and then `Text` as a child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            top: 70,
            right: 50,
            left: 50,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
              ),
              child: Text(
                'some text here',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.pink[700]),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This should work! You only need to wrap the text widget inside a container and provide border in BoxDecoration(). You are placing container as the Text() widget's child which is not possible since Text() widget has no argument called child.